# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException while using jGRASP

Tags: java, class, jgrasp

I keep getting this error: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException in a Mad Lib that I'm making for a class. I am not asking how I can make the code better, just why it won't work. I only get this notification after the third adjective. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scanner_practice {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// Housekeeping
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
String word, story;
int intVar;
double dubVar;

// Introduction
System.out.println("Hi there! I have a great story to tell, but I don't remember some of the words.");
System.out.println("Will you help me? Hooray! Thank you! Here we go...");

// Instructions
System.out.println("\nWhen I ask you for a word or number, just type it. I'll handle the rest.");

// Collect values and bulid the story
System.out.print("Verb: ");
word = kb.next();

story = "I am Dr. Pink and I am destined to " + word;

System.out.print("Adjective: ");
word = kb.next();
kb.nextLine(); // Stops the program skipping
story += "the world! Unfortunately the \n" + "world is full of " + word;

System.out.print("Plural noun:  ");
word = kb.nextLine();

story += " " + word;


System.out.print("Adjective: ");
word = kb.next();

story += "that do not agree. So this is \n" + "my " + word;

System.out.print("Adjective: ");
intVar = kb.nextInt();

story += " plan: To start with, I'll need to build my " + intVar;

System.out.print("Adjetive ");
word = kb.next();

story += " hideout in an /n" + "abandoned " + word; 

System.out.print("Company Name: ");
word = kb.next();

story += " complex in the middle of the" + word; 

System.out.print("Type of Place: ");
word = kb.next();
story += ". All \n" + "the " + word; 

System.out.print("Adjective: ");
word = kb.next();
story += "will address me as 'The Great and " + word; 

System.out.print("Occupation (plural): ");
word = kb.next();
kb.nextLine(); // Stops the program skipping
story += " Dr. Pink.' I will \n" + "hire some  " + word; 

System.out.print("Plural event): ");
word = kb.nextLine();
story += "to design a machine to trigger \n" + "a huge  " + word; 
System.out.print("Plural noun: ");
word = kb.next();
story += " whenever I want it to. And if they don't want to build it, I \n" + "will capture their " + word; 

System.out.print("Something you hate doing: ");
word = kb.next();
story += " and threaten to make them " + word + "for hours on end. \n" + "Muwahahahahaha!"; 


// Print out the story
System.out.println(story);
}

}
```

What do I need to fix? It's due tonight... so if I can get an answer quickly that would mean the world to me! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @Ageax, thank you so much, you're a life saver!

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully the tips on troubleshooting will come in handy with future coding :)